# Web content is rendered twice in ChromiumFX

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am using [ChromiumFX](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx) to render some webcontent in WPF application. But it seems that the content is somehow rendered twice as shown in following screenshot. The bigger one is the expected size which functions correctly while the smaller one doesn't response to any mouse operation. The smaller one acts just as a static picture.

Notice that We have tested the exact same application on Win7/Win8/Win10 on x86/x64 machine with different screen sizes and resolutions. Everything works fine except for Surface Pro 3/4 + Win10. It also works on Surface Pro 1 + Win8.

I guess Chromium kernel is using native Windows API to render behind the scene. So there could be some incompatible problems with Surface hardware, OS API and  Chromium kernel. But to be honest, I don't have any idea where to start the research. Could you guys give me a hint on this? Thanks in advance!

Detailed version info:

- WPF -> 4.0
- ChromiumFX -> 3.2526.1
- CEF -> 3.2526.1359.gced449a
- Chromium -> 47.0.2526.73
- OS -> Win10 65bit
- HW -> Surface Pro 3/4

[image]

Comment: Hi, ChromiumFX author here. I know this is an old issue, but I saw it for the first time today because someone referred to it in the issue tracker (https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx/issues/82/). Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @wborgsm hi, is there any tutorial to set up chromiumfx for any kind of MS Office Addin? I want to start an Outlook Addin and use CFX.

Comment: @Kooki What kind of tutorial you need? Basically it is use the WinForm Control provided in CFX library and embed it in the Outlook VSTO Addin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2016-7-11 Update

After further tests, it seems that the original solution is not the best one. The problem happens again if another monitor is connected to PC and the application window is moved there.

So the final solution should be add app.manifest to the application and enable the `dpiAware` property.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
</windowsSettings>
```

---

Finally got it work. So I will put the answer in case someone runs into same problem.

Actually the problem not only happens in Win10 + Surface Pro. It happens in all devices with win10. Once user changes the default DPI setting, the problem appears.

The workaround for the applications in the filed is to [disable display scaling on high dpi settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2900023) for your application.

And to solve the problem once for all, you may need to add a registry key for your application during installation as follows:

```
Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"

<RegistryValue Type="string" Name="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]ApplicationName.exe" Value="~ HIGHDPIAWARE" />
```

Notice that if you are using a separated process to render, set aforementioned value as the value of `CfxSettings.BrowserSubprocessPath`.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. One note: In addition to the registry solution, it should also be possible to adjust dpi awareness in a manifest file embedded in the application.